# why there is a benchmark difference for opencl code for same graphics card but on different machines?

Tags: c, opencl, gpu

I am using graphics card **Nvidia GeForce GT 630**. and running a program of opencl. Program collects the double array and passed on as an argument to gpu kernel as a buffer. where calculation using this array is done. It takes around 10 mins for performing the job.
machine i am using **Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU**

Similar stats,

machine: **Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU**

graphics card: **GeForce 9500 GT**

time taken for same program is **16 minutes**.

I thought time might be because of different graphics card. Hence i replaced GeForce 9500 GT in Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU with Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU.

but still time is 16minutes. As there is no connection between CPU AND GPU while a program. Can anyone please suggest me, after installing high end graphics card in lower end machine, why there is no improvement in time, because everything is calculated on same GPU only?

thanks in advance.

code for creating kernel:

```
void create_kernel () {
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    fp = fopen("cw_calc.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    cl_uint count;
    clGetPlatformIDs(10, NULL, &count);
    // get all platforms in array platfroms
    platform = (cl_platform_id*) malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id) * count);
    clGetPlatformIDs(count, platform, NULL);

        ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clGetPlatformIDs error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clGetDeviceIDs error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
        /* Create OpenCL context */
        context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clCreateContext error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
        /* Create Command Queue */
        command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clCreateCommandQueue error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
        /*Initialization complete*/

        /* Create Kernel Program from the source */
        program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source_str,(const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clCreateProgramWithSource error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
        /* Build Kernel Program */
    printf("loading GPU kernel..\n");
    system("date");
        ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    system("date");
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clBuildProgram error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        // Determine the size of the log
        size_t log_size;
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &log_size);

        // Allocate memory for the log
        char *log = (char *) malloc(log_size);

        // Get the log
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, log_size, log, NULL);

        // Print the log
        printf("%s\n", log);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("GPU kernel loaded successfuly..\n");
        /* Create OpenCL Kernel */
    printf("creating kernel program..\n");
        kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "gpu_solve", &ret);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clCreateKernel error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("kernel program created successfuly..\n");
}
```

code for executing kernel:

```
int gpu_solve()
{
    printf("Calling gpu_solve\n");
    cl_int ret;
    cl_event event;
    cl_mem spcmBuffer,pvpmBuffer, frmBuffer, ipcmBuffer;;
    size_t global_work_size[1] = {1};
    double sending = 0.0, recv = 0.0, calctime = 0.0;
    double temp = 0.0;
    struct timezone tz;
    struct timeval curr_time;
    gettimeofday(&curr_time, &tz);
    temp = (curr_time.tv_usec/1000000.0) + curr_time.tv_sec;
    spcmBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, numsp * sizeof(double),(void *) cti_spcm, &ret);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clCreateBuffer spcmBuffer error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    pvpmBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, numparams * sizeof(double),(void *) cti_pvpm, &ret);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clCreateBuffer pvpmBuffer error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    frmBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, numreactions * sizeof(double),(void *) cti_frm, &ret);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clCreateBuffer frmBuffer error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    ipcmBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, numsim_spc * sizeof(double),(void *) cti_ipcm, &ret);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clCreateBuffer ipcmBuffer error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&ipcmBuffer);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clSetKernelArg 0 error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&spcmBuffer);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clSetKernelArg 1 error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&pvpmBuffer);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clSetKernelArg 2 error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&frmBuffer);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clSetKernelArg 3 error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, sizeof(int), (void *)&ct_numsim_spc);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clSetKernelArg 4 error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 5, sizeof(double), (void *)&ct_deltime);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clSetKernelArg 5 error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    gettimeofday(&curr_time, &tz);
    sending = ((curr_time.tv_usec/1000000.0) + curr_time.tv_sec) - temp;
    printf("sending time %lf\n",sending);
    gettimeofday(&curr_time, &tz);
    temp = (curr_time.tv_usec/1000000.0) + curr_time.tv_sec;
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, &event);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clEnqueueNDRangeKernel error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
    gettimeofday(&curr_time, &tz);
    calctime = ((curr_time.tv_usec/1000000.0) + curr_time.tv_sec) - temp;
    printf("calctime time %lf\n",calctime);
    gettimeofday(&curr_time, &tz);
    temp = (curr_time.tv_usec/1000000.0) + curr_time.tv_sec;
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, ipcmBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, numsim_spc * sizeof(double), cti_ipcm, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clEnqueueReadBuffer ipcmBuffer error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, spcmBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, numsp * sizeof(double), cti_spcm, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clEnqueueReadBuffer spcmBuffer error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, pvpmBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, numparams * sizeof(double), cti_pvpm, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clEnqueueReadBuffer pvpmBuffer error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, frmBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, numreactions * sizeof(double), cti_frm, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clEnqueueReadBuffer frmBuffer error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(spcmBuffer);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(pvpmBuffer);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(frmBuffer);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(ipcmBuffer);
    gettimeofday(&curr_time, &tz);
    recv = ((curr_time.tv_usec/1000000.0) + curr_time.tv_sec) - temp;
    printf("recv time %lf\n",recv);
    return 0;
}
```

kernel code:

```
void calc_ipcm_cc (__global double* cti_ipcm, __global double* cti_fprm) {
    cti_ipcm[0] = (-cti_fprm[605] + cti_fprm[3135])*5.000000e-01;
    cti_ipcm[1] = (cti_fprm[132] - cti_fprm[1037] + cti_fprm[6734])*1.004016e+01;
    cti_ipcm[2] = (cti_fprm[3993] - cti_fprm[4090])*5.000000e-01;
    .....
    ....
    ~10000 equations to be solved
}

void gpu_eval (__global double* cti_spcm, __global double* cti_pvpm, __global double* cti_fprm) {
    cti_fprm[7632] = ((1.00000000e+00*cti_spcm[2986])/(1.00000000e+00+cti_spcm[2986])) ;
    cti_pvpm[6208] = (((1.00000000e+00*cti_spcm[2986])*1.66000000e+00) );
    cti_pvpm[4434] = (((cti_pvpm[6208]*cti_spcm[212])/(1.00000000e+00+cti_spcm[212])) );
    cti_fprm[7633] = cti_pvpm[4434] ;
    .....
    ....
    ~10000 equations to be solved
}

__kernel void gpu_solve(__global double* cti_ipcm,__global double* cti_spcm, __global double* cti_pvpm, __global double* cti_fprm, int ct_numsim_spc, double ct_deltime)
{
    int i = 0, ispc, mnspcidx;
    ct_deltime = 0.00001;
    double simtime = 0.0;
    while (simtime <= 50000.0) {
        calc_ipcm(cti_ipcm,cti_fprm);
        gpu_eval(cti_spcm,cti_pvpm,cti_fprm);
        simtime = simtime + ct_deltime;
    }

}
```

Comment: different bus (memory bandwith)?

Comment: Pleas provide more information about the code. How are you measuring the time? Are you measuring the transfer between CPU and GPU?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Can you please elaborate more on different bus. Actually i am sending 5 arrays of double datatype to GPU as an argument. and performing solving of equation on GPU for 5 lakh iterations. When task is completed, i read the memory buffer and save in CPU and print them. will there something specific i can benchmark. whole sending(CPU)->calculation(GPU)->receiving(CPU) is together taking more time in different machine. which logically shouldn't

Comment: @brano here i have 5 arrays of double datatype which i am sending to GPU as a buffer as a kernel arguments.. there i am performing solving of equation on GPU for 5 lakh iterations. when task is completed, i read the memory buffer and save in CPU and print them. I will also share the data of benchmark of transferring the data in some time.

Comment: @brano i benchmarked the data for sending and receiving buffers. that is very negligible with the difference i am getting. i am using cl_amd_printf extension and printing values? will that affect?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath benchmark for sending and receiving data differs in both machine. i5 machine does it only in half time as i3. But total time is very negligible for getting the whole time delay.. there might be some other reason?

Comment: printf statements should not be used for more than debug purpouse. This could effect the overall performance because data needs to be sent back to CPU. As Karolay pointed out, you are probably observing different pci-e bandwidth between the two systems. I would suggest to use a profiler and profile the code. Another test you could do is to use a bandwidth test from SDK on both systems to measure the throughput of the pci-e. There is a bandwidth test in CUDA SDK that you could use.

Comment: Thanks @brano i will perform profiling of the code. But i would like to mention that as i had removed all the print statements. still the time difference was there. Is there any other dimension i can check?

Comment: I still don't know excactly how you are timing your calculation. Are you measuring the whole application execution or do you have an isolated timing? Are you timing the memory allocation, array initialization, cpu printing, context creation?

Comment: @brano i am fetching isolated time only.. using gettimeofday. I created a small test case for benchmarking.. for i3 machine: sending buffer and memory allocation: 0.000192 sec. calculation: 88.005525sec. receiving: 0.000220. For i5 machine: sending buffer and memory allocation: 0.000271 sec. calculation: 58.083403sec. receiving: 0.000275. time for kernel building and context creation is 17 secs on i3 machine and 8 sec on i5 machines. Graphics card and driver is exactly same on both machine. this data i had tried thrice on both machines. removed all the printing from the code

Comment: Could you edit your question and attach your code so i could take a close look at it?

Comment: @brano  sorry for the delay... i had added sample code. please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, I am pretty sure you are using CPU instead of GPU.
Because if it is taking you 16M to finish only 1 kernel, the GPU driver would reboot.

Comment: Thanks much @DarkZeros for pointing out. please suggest some fix

Comment: actually i tried all CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL. for me only last two works. @DarkZeros rest are exitting because of -1 error. "CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND". Can i check using another way i am using CPU instead of GPU?